# Go to definition emacs evil with xref-js2

Tags: javascript, emacs, evil-mode, js2-mode

I'm trying to switch to emacs from vim. I've installed js2-mode, xref-js2 and evil of course. And when I try to go to definition with `M-.` I get the message: "Previous command was not evil repeat:..." and previous command. So is there any way (work around) to get this work?
P.S It works just fine in emacs mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that evil mode has build in solution for this. It works with `C-]`